# How to rename a folder using ZipArchive?

Tags: php, zend-framework, unzip

is there any solution to rename a folder inside zipfile before unzipping ?

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$result=$zip->renameName($acfoldername , $renameFolder );
```

Function renameName seems only to rename files and not folders

```
$zip->renameName($acfoldername , $renameFolder );
```

OR
 **is there any solution in Zend Framework for zip file management?**

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Sorry , but there is no class in the ZF that able to rename folder inside of the ZIP file

but again there is nothing impossible you can use the same ZipArchive to extract the file somewhere and then using the function [`Glob`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) or [`SPL Directory Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) "

to locate your wanted folder using [`rename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) and the last step is to zip your folder again using the same `ZipArchive`

example of creating zip file : http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php

Answer (score 9):

rename directory inside zipfile using ZipArchive :-)

```
$tmpfile = "myzip.zip";
copy( "template.zip", $tmpfile );

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open( $tmpfile, ZipArchive::CREATE );

if ($res === TRUE) {
  $index = "<html>content</html>";

  $zip->addFromString('dirname/index.html', $index);
  $zip->addFile("mp3/sample.mp3", 'dirname/audio/myAudioFile.mp3');

  // rename directory "dirname"
  $name="newDirectoryName";
  $i=0;
  while($item_name = $zip->getNameIndex($i)){
    $zip->renameIndex( $i, str_replace( "dirname", $name, $item_name ) );
    $i++;
  }

  $zip->close();

  header('Content-type: application/zip');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'.zip"');
  readfile($tmpfile);
  unlink($tmpfile);
}
```